# Undefined onKeyDown inside SherlockFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

Im getting the following error when using the below code

`The method onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent) is undefined for the type SherlockFragment`

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep this kind of thing out of your fragment. The following code worked for me in my MainActivity with 4 tabs that each have their own web view.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int currPage = mPager.getCurrentItem();
    WebView wv = null;
    switch (currPage) {
    case 0:
        wv = (WebView) mPager.getChildAt(currPage).findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        break;
    case 1:
        wv = (WebView) mPager.getChildAt(currPage).findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        break;
    case 2:
        wv = (WebView) mPager.getChildAt(currPage).findViewById(R.id.webView3);
        break;
    case 3:
        wv = (WebView) mPager.getChildAt(currPage).findViewById(R.id.webView4);
        break;
    }

    if (wv != null) {
        if (wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

edit: I ran into trouble on my 4th tab and the solution for me was to set the webView in my fragment(Tab0.java) static. Then directly referencing it in my main activity.

```
switch (currPage) {
    case 0:
        wv = Tab0.webView;
        break;
    case 1:
        wv = Tab1.webView;
        break;
    case 2:
        wv = Tab2.webView;
        break;
    case 3:
        wv = Tab3.webView;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Activity should manage the back button not the fragment. If you want the fragment to manage the onKeyDown, you can attach  the `OnKeyListener`, on the view returned by `getView()`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, container, false);
    view.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
                // here your code
          } 
     });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After done few research. i found this ! 
Hopefully its help.

```
root =(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_f_other, container, false);

    root.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {
                      @Override
                      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
                          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                            //Do something
                          }
                        return false;

                      } 
                 });
```